# Entropy and enthalpy of hydrogen ion?

Tags: aqueous-solution, enthalpy, entropy

The absolute entropy of $\ce{H^+ (g)}$  is  $\ce{108 kJ/mol.K}$. However, the absolute entropy of $\ce{H^+ (aq)}$ is exactly 0. Why is that? Also, the standard enthalpy of $\ce{H^+ (aq)}$ is 0, so what is it the standard state of?

Comment: For H+, it is simply conventionally defined as such. It is not the same as the value for H2(g), which is 0 because H2(g) is the standard state of hydrogen.

Comment: Its entropy is not zero, but you can define (arbitrary) a reference state.

Comment: The reference state can not be the two states at the same time. You should give more details about your problem.